# If Statement Advice Needed

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I’m trying to show an alert when a value greater than 200 is entered in my `UITextField`, `rcdAtIan.text`. I’ve tried this:

```
 Self.rcdAtIan.text = self.circuit.rcdAtIan;
    if (_rcdAtIan.text > @"200");{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Value Exceeded" message:@"Message here............." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
           [alert show];
```

and then this:

```
Self.rcdAtIan.text = self.circuit.rcdAtIan;
 if (self.circuit.rcdAtIan > @"200");{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Value Exceeded" message:@"Message here.........." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
           [alert show];
    }
```

but the alert is being shown when the view is loaded, rather than by my `if` statement. I know what I’m trying to say — `if (_rcdAtIan.text => 200 "show my alert");` — but I’m unsure of the correct syntax.

Comment: "Self" is either a typo or a very bad variable name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to perform an arithmetic comparison on 2 string values. What you need to do is ask:

```
if ([_rcdAtIan.text intValue] > 200) {...
```

Comment: @JSA986 If this answer solved your problem then please mark it as accepted by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.

Comment: Yeah done it now, it wouldn't let me accept for the pre defined time when I tried first time.

Answer (score 4):

You can't compare strings like this (well, you can, but it doesn't make sense, since it performs a numerical comparison of the pointers which represent the strings, and **it does not compare the contents of the strings**). So, you may want to convert the strings to numerical values:

```
if ([self.circuit.rcdAtIan intValue] >= 200) {
    // "200" or more has been entered
}
```

Comment: Thank you H2CO3. plus one, and thanks for explaining about comparing strings